# HHVM Warmup Flow

Tags: hhvm

I have included server.hdf in my hhvm server startup command.

```
Server {
    WarmupRequests {
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
        * = /var/www/app/hhvm_warmup.php
    }
}
```

Here is my php.ini

```
; php options
;
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /var/lib/php5
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

; hhvm specific
hhvm.jit_warmup_requests = 10

hhvm.server.port=9000
hhvm.server.type=fastcgi
hhvm.server.source_root=/var/www/app/public
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php

hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.level = Warning 
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.log.header = true
hhvm.log.use_sys_log = true
hhvm.log.injected_stack_trace = true
hhvm.log.native_stack_trace = true
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 1
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false

hhvm.hack.lang.look_for_typechecker = false
hhvm.utf8 = true
```

A little finicky as I used to see the warmup logs in /var/log/hhvm/error.log but now I see failed database errors. These errors come from the application not knowing which environment to load base on the base url. I can't pin point where these requests failures are coming from. Is hhvm sending requests to the application somehow?